# Getting NullPointer Exception for not explicable reason sometimes when I click on icon that should open new frame

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mouseevent

```
public class Sticky
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextPane textPane;
    private JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    private static Point POINT = new Point(0,0);
    private static int frameUp = 0;
    private static Clip clip;
    private static boolean musicOn = false;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;

   public Sticky()
    {
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        makeFrame();
    }

    private void makeFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Dimension dem = new Dimension(250,220);
        textPane.setPreferredSize(dem);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        makeMenu();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { doThis(); }
        });
        frame.pack();
    }

    public void doThis()
    {
        if(isPlaying)
        {
            Sticky.clip.close();
            Sticky.frameUp--;
            Sticky.musicOn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Sticky.frameUp--;
        }
    }

    private void makeMenu()
    {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New Note");
        newItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { newNote(); }
        });
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        JMenuItem importItem = new JMenuItem("Import Text");
        importItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { importText(); }
        });
        fileMenu.add(importItem);
        JMenuItem exportItem = new JMenuItem("Export Text");
        exportItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { exportText(); }
        });
        fileMenu.add(exportItem);

        JMenu insertMenu = new JMenu("Insert...");
        JMenuItem imageInsert = new JMenuItem("Image");
        imageInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { addImage(); }
        });
        insertMenu.add(imageInsert);
        JMenuItem soundInsert = new JMenuItem("Sound");
        soundInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { addSound(); }
        });
        insertMenu.add(soundInsert);
        fileMenu.add(insertMenu);

    }

    private void addSound()
    {
        int val = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if(val != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            return;
        }
       // if(!chooser.getSelectedFile().getName().contains(".wav"))
        //{
            //error
         //   return;
        //}
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("sound.png");
        JButton button = new JButton(icon);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { playSound(chooser.getSelectedFile()); }
        });
        textPane.insertComponent(button);
    }

    private void playSound(File file)
    {
        if(Sticky.musicOn)
        {
            Sticky.musicOn = false;
            isPlaying = false;
            Sticky.clip.close();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            Sticky.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            Sticky.clip.open(audio);
            Sticky.clip.start();
            Sticky.musicOn = true;
            isPlaying = true;
        }
        catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void addImage()
    {
        int val = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if(val != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            return;
        }
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
        textPane.insertIcon(icon);
        textPane.setCaretPosition(textPane.getText().length());
    }

    private void exportText()
    {
        try
        {
            int val = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
            if(val != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                return;
            }
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getPath() + ".txt");
            writer.write(textPane.getText());
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            //jtextpane
        }
    }

    private void importText()
    {
        int val = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if(val != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            //jtextpane
            return;
        }
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try
        {
            textPane.read(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)), file);
            textPane.setCaretPosition(textPane.getText().length());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            //jtextpane
        }
    }

    private void newNote()
    {
        Sticky.POINT = frame.getLocation();
        if(Sticky.POINT.getY() >= 500)
        {
            Sticky.POINT = new Point((int)Sticky.POINT.getX()+300, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Sticky.POINT = new Point((int)Sticky.POINT.getX(), (int)Sticky.POINT.getY()+250);
        }
        Sticky stick = new Sticky();
        stick.frame.setLocation(Sticky.POINT);
        stick.frame.setVisible(true);
        Sticky.frameUp++;
    }

    private static void openFrame()
    {
        if(Sticky.frameUp == 0)
        {
            Sticky stick = new Sticky();
            stick.frame.setVisible(true);
            Sticky.frameUp = 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("note.jpg");
            TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(image.getImage());
            icon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { openFrame(); }
            });
            tray.add(icon);
        }
    catch(AWTException e)
    {
        return;
    }
        Sticky.musicOn = false;
        Sticky stick = new Sticky();
        stick.frame.setVisible(true);
        Sticky.frameUp = 1;
    }
}
```

It happens sometimes but most of the time it is fine. I have tried catching the exception as the exception does nothing but print to the terminal and does not affect the running of the program, but this does not work either. Here is the rest of my code. Its basically a stickies program that creates a new sticky when there are no more frames open when icon is pressed. Sometimes when frame is open and pressed an exception will occur but only sometimes.

Here is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.eventDispatched(Container.java:4742)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$SelectiveAWTEventListener.eventDispatched(Toolkit.java:2425)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$ToolkitEventMulticaster.eventDispatched(Toolkit.java:2317)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.notifyAWTEventListeners(Toolkit.java:2275)
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.dispatchEvent(TrayIcon.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:763)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Does the exception that prints to the terminal indicate the line the exception was thrown on? How about the stack trace?

Comment: no line in my own code is printed out :(

Comment: Show us the stacktrace anyway.  We won't be able to help you otherwise.   (Apart from pointing you at the generic Q&A that explains how to diagnose NPEs.)

Comment: Also, show us the `Stick` class, because your `openFrame` method is potentially causing the problem.

Comment: okay i updated it